# Why I cannot pass a csv handler to a python thread function?

Tags: python-3.x

```
import threading
import csv

csv_content = []

def load_csv(f_csv):
   global csv_content
   heading = next(f_csv)
   print("heading: {0}".format(heading))
  for lin in f_csv:
      print(lin)
      csv_content.append(lin)

def main():
  with open('test.csv', 'rt') as f:
      f_csv = csv.reader(f)
      threadA = threading.Thread(target=load_csv, args=(f_csv,))
      threadA.start()

  global csv_content
  curr_idx = 0
  while curr_idx < len(csv_content):
      print("[{0}]: {1}".format(curr_idx, csv_content[curr_idx]))
      curr_idx += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

> ```
> File "thread_csv.py", line 8, in load_csv
>     heading = next(f_csv)
> StopIteration
> ```

I just found that the code will fail if I pass the csv handler to a python threading function as above. Instead, if I pass the filename it will work.

Question> Can someone share some light with me why we are not able to pass the csv file handler to a threading function?

Thank you

==== Update Working code ===

```
  1 import threading
  2 import csv
  3
  4 csv_content = []
  5
  6 def load_csv(file_name):
  7     with open(file_name, 'rt') as f:
  8         f_csv = csv.reader(f)
  9         global csv_content
 10         heading = next(f_csv)
 11         print("heading: {0}".format(heading))
 12         for lin in f_csv:
 13             print(lin)
 14             csv_content.append(lin)
 15
 16 def main():
 17     threadA = threading.Thread(target=load_csv, args=('test.csv',))
 18     threadA.start()
 19
 20     global csv_content
 21     curr_idx = 0
 22     while curr_idx < len(csv_content):
 23         print("[{0}]: {1}".format(curr_idx, csv_content[curr_idx]))
 24         curr_idx += 1
 25
 26 if __name__ == "__main__":
 27     main()
```

Comment: What was your code when passing the file?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ please see my update post. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. This code is the culprit:

```
with open('test.csv', 'rt') as f:
    f_csv = csv.reader(f)
    threadA = threading.Thread(target=load_csv, args=(f_csv,))
    threadA.start()
```

What happens after you call `.start()`? You exit the manager. The manager closes the file, and the handler is now pointing to a closed file. Hence the `StopIteration`. This is somewhat of a race condition.

To fix this, you'll need to wait for the thread to complete inside the context manager, so call `threadA.join()`:

```
with open('test.csv', 'rt') as f:
    ...
    threadA.start()
    threadA.join()
```

Alternatively, don't use a context manager - open the file with `f = open(...)` and then start the thread as normal.

Comment: This explains why it works sometime and doesn't work other time. I will change the code so that the threading function will open the handler itself. Many thanks for saving hours of debug

Comment: @q0987 That is definitely another alternative. Glad I could help. :)